# What event is fired when user dictates to an INPUT element on iPad 3?

Tags: webkit, mobile-safari

Just got the new iPad, and when I touch the microphone and say a word, it appears in an input element on my web page. Yay! But I want to dynamically update as the user types, and it isn't firing the "onkeyup" event that I'm listening for. Boo!

onchange isn't firing either (unless I press the "keyboard go away" button).

Any suggestions for what event handler I should be listening for on html INPUT elements, so that mobile safari will call me when the user says something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, in case you are wondering, is `oninput`. In my case, I could just substitute `oninput` everywhere I had `onkeyup`.